# Module not found: Can't resolve mp3 Import NextJs Javascript

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to import audio file 'intro.mp3' from public/audio to my Introduction.js file.
But I get this error

```
./components/Introduction.js:4:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '/audio/intro.mp3'
  2 | import { Button, Flex, Box, WrapItem } from "@chakra-ui/react";
  3 | import useSound from "use-sound";
> 4 | import Intro from "/audio/intro.mp3";
  5 | 
  6 | export default function Introduction() {
  7 |   const [play, { stop }] = useSound(Intro);

Import trace for requested module:
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

I'm trying the same code with react-app and it's working fine without error, but when in NextJs it's became an error, I'm not using typescript in my NextJs project.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Button, Flex, Box, WrapItem } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import useSound from "use-sound";
import Intro from "/audio/intro.mp3";

export default function Introduction() {
    const [play, { stop }] = useSound(Intro);

    return (
        <>
            <Flex>
                <Box>
                    <Button
                        variant="ghost"
                        p="4"
                        size="lg"
                        onMouseEnter={() => play()}
                        onMouseLeave={() => stop()}>
                        Welcome to Interactive Learning Application
                    </Button>
                </Box>
            </Flex>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: 1.) Don't post code as images and 2.) you probably want `./audio/intro.mp3` instead of `/audio/intro.mp3`. The latter is an absolute path.

Comment: thanks, for answering. Unfortunately it's still error. but I'm now got it solve

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement should with absolute path.

Change the line of code of import mp3 file

```
import Intro from "/audio/intro.mp3";
```

With

```
import Intro from "./audio/intro.mp3";
```